# How many different words can be made up by rearranging the letters in the word SPECIAL so that no two of the letters I, A and E go in a row?

Tags: combinatorics

My solution is:

> 7! - A(2, 3) * 6 - A(3, 3) * 5

it's equal to 4973. Clearly too much but i can't find my mistake... What's the correct solution then?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You should explain how you arrived at your solution, which helps readers of your question detect any errors you may have made.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

Write $X$ for one of the letters from $\{S, P,C, L\}$. The allowed words are then of the form
$${}_-\ X\ {}_-\ X\ {}_-\ X\ {}_-\ X\ {}_-\quad,$$
where each of the slots $\ {}_-\ $can be filled with at most one of the letters from $\{E, I, A\}$.